# TDMS + Bokeh hoveringtool names

Tags: python, bokeh

I exported some TDMS files to python and convert them to different data frames.

I am trying to plot the dfs and have their name displayed in the hovertool. I am able to get the Voltage & Current values but I am missing their names.

Is there a more efficient way of doing it or is my approach correct at least?

Here is my code.

```
# In[1]:         
from nptdms import TdmsFile

AA = TdmsFile(r"C:\Users\A.tdms")
BA = TdmsFile(r"C:\Users\B.tdms")

for group in AA.groups():
    A = AA.object(group).as_dataframe()
for group in BA.groups():
    B = BA.object(group).as_dataframe()

# In[2]:
  
Time = [x/10 for x in range(0, len(A))]    #10Hz -> x/10 = Hz 

A.insert(loc=0, column='Time', value=Time) #Insert column of time
B.insert(loc=0, column='Time', value=Time) #Insert column of time

# In[3]:         

Ax = A['Time']
A1 = A['Voltage']        
A2 = A['Current']           

Bx = B['Time']
B1 = B['Voltage']        
B2 = B['Current'] 

# In[4]:

TOOLTIPS_1 = [
    ("Name", "@name")
    ("Time", "$x sec"),
    ("Voltage", "$y V"),
]

TOOLTIPS_2 = [
    ("Material", "@col")
    ("Time", "$x sec"),
    ("Current", "$y A"),
]

p = [figure(title="Voltage", tooltips=TOOLTIPS_1)]
p.append(figure(title="Current", tooltips=TOOLTIPS_2))
        
# In[5]:

color = 20
width = 3

# Voltage
p[0].line(Ax, A1, legend = 'A', line_color = Category20[color][0], line_width = width)
p[0].line(Bx, B1, legend = 'B', line_color = Category20[color][3], line_width = width)

# Current
p[1].line(Ax, A2, legend = 'A', line_color = Category20[color][0], line_width = width)
p[1].line(Bx, B2, legend = 'B', line_color = Category20[color][3], line_width = width)


# In[6]:

#Configuration of the plot title, ticks, legend etc.
for i in range (0,len(p)):
    #Title
    p[i].title.text_font_size = '20pt'
    #Legend
    p[i].legend.title = 'Legend'
    p[i].legend.location = "top_right"  

    #Axis ticks
    p[i].axis.major_tick_out = 10
    p[i].axis.minor_tick_in = -3
    p[i].axis.minor_tick_out = 8

# In[7]:

output_file('Voltage_Current.html', title= 'Box V_C')
show(column([p[0], p[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into using `ColumnDataSource`, it will probably save you a bunch of code and iterations, and maybe make it clearer for yourself too.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html

(Sorry, don't have time at the moment to make an exact example for your case).